# Angular2 - call function from main.bundle.js / mermaid click event

Tags: angular, mermaid

I am working with Angular2 within Electron seeded from https://github.com/maximegris/angular-electron

I have installed Mermaid and got it working nearly exactly as I need it. My flowchart does display correctly as intended.

The only problem that I am having is with the click event.

(See interaction section of this page https://mermaidjs.github.io/flowchart.html)

Where I need to define within my mermaid markup `click A callback` and A will be passed to the call back.

The problem that I have is that 'callback' must be a native javascript function not a typescript function. I am targeting a "BoxClick" function with in my ProjectManagementPageConnectionsComponent. And I can see that in main.bundle.js it is compiled to something similar to: `ProjectManagementPageConnectionsComponent.prototype.BoxClick = function () {`

And when debugging in the console I try to execute `ProjectManagementPageConnectionComponent.BoxClick();` but it says that ProjectManagementPageConnectionComponent is not defined. but in main.bundle.js it looks like it is defined. So is there a parent namespace above it that I am missing? Because I am pretty sure if I can get this function to work in the console, then I can call that function in my mermaid markup too.

In the end I want a navigation to happen from there. Now according to the mermaid docs documentation I can define a URL. And I have done that and it does work; however, it opens in a new window. I want it to navigate within the same window and it appears the only way to do that is by using a function. But the namespace of the function seems unreachable.

Comment: `ProjectManagementPageConnectionsComponent.prototype.BoxClick` is an instance method, so you would have to do `new ProjectManagementPageConnectionComponent().BoxClick();`. Not saying that is your only issue here, just that would be one of them.

Comment: I like it but ya in the console `new ProjectManagementPageConnectionComponent().BoxClick();` still says `Uncaught ReferenceError: ProjectManagementPageConnectionComponent is not defined` which reading what i can of the main.bundle.js file just doesn't make any sense why it would say that it is not defined, because it looks clearly defined to me.

Comment: It probably is scoped within an IIFE or something and thus isn't in the global scope (aka as a property on the window object).

Comment: You'll probably have to create a global scoped function in your TS class like `window.handleBoxClick = function () {};`.

Comment: Yep I kinda did something like that. I went ahead and to the assets folder added a new javascript file. Then in the index.html I src'd it in. The function now accepts the argument and just does a dirty window.location.href to the route that i want and it works just fine. back buttons work too. So I feel good about it. I didn't know that I could create a function within the window namespace in a TS class I may try that too. Thanks for everything.

Comment: I am facing the similar issue.  Did someone get this working?  I tried with window.CustomFunction = function() {}; in TS class, but it give me compile error like 
     "error TS1005: ';' expected.
69 window.CustomFunction = function () {};"